# Fake car in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project where I need to populate the database with some car data.

I see this library to extend $faker.

> https://github.com/pelmered/fake-car

The problem is the documentation shows how can implemente in old versions of Laravel. In v8 seeds and providers has some changed so i can´t implement it how documentation says.

So my question is: How can extend faker? How can i use it this library in Laravel 8?

**UPDATE 1**

I try something like that

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

use App\Models\Car;

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

class CarFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Car::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {

    
    $factory->define(Car::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    
        $faker->addProvider(new \Faker\Provider\Fakecar($faker));
        $v = $faker->vehicleArray();

        return [
            'model' => $this->faker->name(12),
            'brand' => $this->faker->lastName(12),
            'color' => $this->faker->hexColor(),
            'license' => $this->faker->unique()->bothify('#######'),
        ];
    }
 })
}
```

But returns that *$factory* is undefined.

**UPDATE 2**

I use this command to create factory

```
php artisan make:factory CarFactory
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: All the stuff that `define` function can go in the `definition` function of the new style factory classes. Should be a pretty easy conversion.

Comment: Updated: Added the code I tested.

Comment: Well, `$factory` is in fact undefined. How did you create that factory? Using `php artisan make:factory`? If not, have you tried that? There's also https://github.com/laravel/legacy-factories - so you can use the "old" way in L8

Comment: Updated: Added the command that i use to create factory.

Comment: You should probably just remove the closure with `$factory->define() {...}`

Comment: Take a step back and think about what you are doing instead of doing random cutting and pasting of code. Why would ` $factory->define` be in the factory class definition? Why refer to the faker both as `$faker` and `$this->faker` ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the provider to the existing Faker instance, which resides in `$this->faker`:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

use App\Models\Car;

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

class CarFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Car::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {

        $this->faker->addProvider(new \Faker\Provider\Fakecar($this->faker));
        $v = $this->faker->vehicleArray();

        return [
            'model' => $v['model'],
            'brand' => $v['brand'],
            'color' => $this->faker->hexColor(),
            'license' => $this->faker->unique()->bothify('#######'),
        ];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Return undefinied variable $faker.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre Use `$this->faker` in the `new \Faker\Provider\Fakecar` bit.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre I'm glad. Be aware that we usually are typing from memory and can't fully test the solutions like this; you may have to make minor tweaks from time to time to correct things like this.